# lodash not working as an inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have this javascript eventlistener (since `$(document).on('scroll...);` just ouright didn't work):

`document.addEventListener("wheel", function() {}, true);`

I now have a stuff I want to do every time the listener is triggered and some taxing stuff I want to trigger only at certain times with [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash). For testing I made it simple:

```
_.debounce(function() {
    console.log("triggered");
}, 200);
```

The question/problem is that it works when I put it in a separate eventlistener like so..

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", _.debounce(function() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("triggered");
}, 200), true);
```

..but when I put it in the other with the rest as a nested function like this..

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", function() {
    "use strict";

    //other code that fires every time the listener is triggered

    _.debounce(function() {
        console.log("triggered");
    }, 200);    
}, true);
```

..it does not work at all. I appreciate every idea and help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.debounce` *creates* a debounced function but does not execute it or bind it to anything by default; `_.debounce` is a higher-order function, so when you call it, it returns the function you'd want to pass as an argument to the listener. So, it doesn't work when you declare it inside your anonymous listener function in your last snippet.

If you want to attach something that's *not* debounced like that as well, just add it separately:

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", _.debounce(function() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("triggered");
}, 200), true);
document.addEventListener("wheel", () => {
  // other code that fires every time the listener is triggered
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! So the only way are two seperate eventlisteners?

Comment: Another option would be to create the debounced function separately, and then call both the debounced function and the other code inside a single listener. But adding multiple listeners is completely fine.

Comment: The problem is I need some stuff from the other code in the debounce function. Which way is the most efficient to do that?

Comment: `Which way is the most efficient to do that? ` The one event listener, as you could just then use a closure.

Comment: @MiXT4PE As Keith said, use a single listener so that the debounce function has lexical scope of the main listener block

Comment: @Keith I am really sorry but I don't really get the concept both of you are trying to convey. I guess my javascript knowledge is too limited :/ Could you maybe provide a recourse?

Comment: @MiXT4PE I've posted an answer with a working snippet for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what @CertainPerformance is saying with using 1 event.

```js
const doBounced = _.debounce(function(v) {
  console.log(v);
}, 200);


document.addEventListener("wheel", function() {
  const n = new Date();
  console.log("triggered");
  doBounced(n);
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I get! Thank you, Sir!